# Convert console.writeline to RichTextBox.AppendText() c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console

I have some code that reads the ssid and rssi from multiple access points. However it is a console app and I need to convert it to a winform app.

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
            foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found network with SSID {0} and Siqnal Quality {1}.", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid), network.wlanSignalQuality);
            }
```

I wish to convert the line that prints the list in the console to a line (or lines) that will print to a rich text box. Everything I have tried has resulted in just printing one entry from the list.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Thanks for the responses, here's what I went with..

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("Found network with SSID---" + GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid) + "and Siqnal Quality---" + rssi + "\n")
```

Comment: @SLaks I have extended the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure the Multiline property to true on the RichTextBox (this is the default so it should be). Use the RichTextBox.AppendText() method and make sure you add a newline character to the end of your string.

Comment: Closest to what I ended up doing. I split up the literal and put the variables between the comments. It was the dumb ole new line i was missing out on! \n\n\n\n

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that you are building up a list of networks, for multiple string appends, I would advise using a `StringBuilder` [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Something like this should work:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork Network network in networks)
{
    string ssidString = GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid);
    builder.AppendFormat("Found network with SSID {0} and Signal Quality {1}.", ssidString , network.wlanSignalQuality).AppendLine();
}
textBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    TextBox.Lines= networks.Select(n => string.Format("Found network with SSID {0} and Signal Quality {1}.", n.dot11Ssid, n.wlanSignalQuality)).ToArray();
```